# Change layout on submenus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm trying to make sub-menus for my menu, but something just isn't right and I cant seem to change the colour and layout of the submenus itself.

```
* { margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html {height: 100%;}

body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#fff));

}

.navbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}


ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: :;0px;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background: url(shad2.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
    display: inline-table;
}




li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

ul.nav li a  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: #cbcbcb url() no-repeat;
    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}
ul.nav li ul { display:none;
 }
ul.nav li:hover ul { 
display:block; }


<div class="navbox">
  <ul class="nav">

  <div class="navbox">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Program</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
<li><a href="#">El</a></li>
</ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I've been looking at a guide, http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu
If you look at the 4th picture, you'll see how I want my own dropdowns to look, even tho the code is there, I've tried to fix the problem myself. So the problem is, when I try to change the layout to look like the one on the 4th picture, it wont change thesubmenu dropdown layout, it'll just create a weird looking box under the boxlayout it self.

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:absolute` to your hovering  it will start to work:

```
ul.nav li:hover ul { 
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Then add a background(-color) and some other styling and you can get to this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/zz83R/1/ (based on your code)

Good luck!